# Service stack elmah implementation

Tags: c#, servicestack, elmah

We have recently updated the version of ServiceStack.Logging.Elmah and the code that used to work in our older version no longer works:

```
        ServiceExceptionHandler += (request, exception) =>
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(context).Log(new Error(exception,context));
            return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
        };
```

It doesnt compile on the exception variables for new Error(). I have tried casting them to Exception but this just causes another error on the whole lot of code 'Cannot apply operator '+=' to operands of type 'ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.HandleServiceExceptionDelegate' and 'lambda expression'. Struggling to find any documentation for the update, could anyone let me know what the code change is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for `ServiceExceptionHandler` is now:

```
ServiceExceptionHandler += (httpReq, request, exception) => { .. }
```

I recommend joining the [ServiceStack G+ Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445) to get notified of any breaking changes during releases.